# Python 3.7 tkinter 8 - change a menu items 'command' option on the fly

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a tkinter application and trying to implement a model view controller pattern.

I have a View class:

```
class View(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Set up and display the user interface """
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.menubar = Menu(master)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Login")
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Register")
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Exit", command=master.quit)
        self.master = master
        self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)
```

and in my Controller I would like to set the 'command' option for menubar item 'Login' like so ( because I don't want my view handling login logic ):

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = View(self.root)
```

--->      self.view.menubar [set command for 'login' item = self.test() ] <--  The syntax here is what I am trying to figure out.  Tkinter documentation is not very helpful and most blog posts offer very simplistic examples.  I have tried something like:  `self.view.menubar.entryconfigure(0, command=self.test)` but no luck.

```
    def run(self):
        self.root.title("Password Manager Application")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def test(self):
        print("Asdf")
```

Thanks for your help,
Marc

Comment: Your attempt with `.entryconfigure()` should have worked - could you be more specific than "no luck" as to what went wrong when you tried?

Comment: This `.entryconfigure(0...` should read `.entryconfigure(1`, it's **1-based**-

Comment: @stovfl: you are incorrect:  it's zero-based. However, item zero may be the part of the menu that lets you tear it off on some platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
You can actually try using `entryconfig(1, command=new_cmd)`

An alternative approach you can do is to make these changes within the command function and place it in the controller code.

An example

```
def login_cmd(self):
    if self.login_cmd_option == 'A':
        self.login_A()
    else:
        self.login_B()

def set_login_cmd(login_cmd_option):
    self.login_cmd_option = login_cmd_option
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to use `itemconfigure`.  However, item zero may not be the item you think it is. If you don't set `tearoff` to `False`, item zero may be the tearoff item.

You can use the item's label instead of an number for the index, which guarantees the correct item is changed (assuming the label doesn't change).

Example:

```
self.view.menubar.entryconfigure("Login", command=self.test)
```